# How to add a list of new labels to ggplot loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

Hi I have about 30 plots I'm trying to make hence the need for a loop to plot my graphs!
The current variable labels have '.''s in between words e.g IgG.titre

For my final graphs I would like to have my x axis label with a space rather than the dot or dash between words. I have tried modifying the variable names before hand so they are 'pretty' and have spaces, but as expected R does not seem to like that and I get a parsing error message.

I have saved a character vector 'prettynames' with the nice labels I would like to use for my x axis, but I am struggling to add them into the loop. Any help is much appreciated. Below is the code I am using for my plotting loop

Here's some dummy data:

```
Foldchange <- c(500, 600, 400)
age <- c(23, 41, 32)
IgG.1 <- c(10, 20, 30)
IgG.2 <- c(13, 45, 20)

df <- data.frame(age, Foldchange, IgG.1, IgG.2)

prettynames <- c("Age", "Fold Change", "IgG 1", "IgG 2")
colnames <- names(df)

Y <- df$Foldchange
```

Plotting Loop

```
for(i in colnames){
  plt <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i, y = Y)) +
    geom_point(color="#B20000", size=3.6, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=0.06, color="black") + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, alpha=0.25, color="black", fill="black") + ylab ("ADNP Fold Change") + xlab(prettynames[i]) + stat_cor(method = "pearson")
  print(plt)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

The xlab(prettynames) is where I would like to loop over my new list of nice names. Thanks for any help in advance - sorry I am quite new to using loops still!

Comment: I'm unclear about whether the axis title or the axis labels have points in them. However, `scale_x_discrete(name = gsub("\\.", " ", i))` should work for titles and `scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x){gsub("\\.", " ", x)})` should work for labels. Or take `scale_x_continuous()` instead, I can't tell from this question.

Comment: You could try with `xlab(gsub("(\\.|\\-)", " ", i))` which will replace `.` or `-` with a space without the need of `prettynames` or you could make `prettynames` a named vector like so `prettynames <- setNames(prettynames, colNames2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using xlab(gsub("(\\.|\\-)", " ", i)) worked a treat :)